# Circumference of a circle with known cord length and circumcircular arclength

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, arc-length

I have been trying to figure out a way to relate the length of a string that is curved into a circumcircle, along with the distance between the two ends of that string, to the arclength created by that chord.  I have drawn a sketch below.

[image]

I tried using the following relations (to no avail):

[image]

$s=R\theta$

$a=2Rsin(\theta / 2)$

$\theta = 2sin^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{2R}\right)$

$s \approx \sqrt{c^2 + \frac{16}{3}h^2 } $

...all of which involve unknowns.  I've even tried combining these equations to find a simplification... again, no avail.

Can this be done?

Comment: Another relation you can use is $\frac{\theta}{2 \pi} = \frac{x}{x + g}$, where $x$ and $g$ are as in your first image and $\theta$ the second.

Answer (score 0):

You have not used all that you know: you know the length of the string, $g$.

Using the original notation from the first diagram for the arc length, the chord and the length of the string and $R$ and $\theta$ as defined in the second diagram:

$$ x = R\theta $$

$$ g = R(2\pi - \theta) $$

$$ e = 2R\sin{\theta \over 2} $$

$g$ and $e$ are known, $x$, $R$ and $\theta$ are unknown. We have three equations in three unknowns, so in theory you could find $x$.

You could for instance take the ratio of the second and third equations to eliminate R and come up with a (not quite straightforward) equation for $\theta$. With $\theta$ known, determining $R$ and $x$ is trivial.

Comment: Very helpful!  I used $g=R(2\pi-\theta)$ to get $R=\frac{g}{2\pi-\theta}$.  I know that $d=2R sin(\frac{\theta}{2})=2 \left( \frac{g}{2\pi-\theta} \right) sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$ which is exactly the kind of solution that I was looking for.

Comment: As a general rule, you should refrain from introducing multiple symbols for the same quantity: what's called $e$ in the first diagram is called $a$ in the second and then $d$ in your comment. Choose one and stick with it!